# Get number of rows in each partition of Spark in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 10000 records in a csv file and after read these file data I am doing repartition using 5 
`Dataset<Row> partionDataSet = csvDataset.repartition(5);` 
But I am not able to get that how many records each partition has.
Is there any way to find out this in Java

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can count the items in each partition.

> ```
> LongAccumulator accum = sc.sc().longAccumulator();
>
> JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"));
>  rdd.foreachPartition(iter -> {
>
>   while (iter.hasNext()) {
>    accum.add(1);
>   }
>  });
>  print(accum.value().intValue());
> ```

You can of course make a better accumulator using a [MAP accumulator](https://www.brosinski.com/post/extending-spark-accumulators/).  It will allow you to collect individual numbers from each parition.

in scala you could say something like this, I'm sure there is a java Equivalent. (or you can use mapPartitionsWithIndex())

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext
partionDataSet.foreachPartition(
  it => { 
    var i = 0;
    while(it.hasNext) { i+=1; it.next(); }; 
    println(TaskContext.getPartitionId + ":"+i.toString)
})
```